# What is an algebraic technique to evaluate changes to the fixed point?

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I am looking at a 1-D dynamical system in a generic form $\dot{y}=g(y,\rho),$ where $\rho$ is a parameter.

All I know about it is that this function has a fixed point at $y=0$ and when $\rho=0$.  If I change $\rho$ slightly, how can I algebraically determine the impact on the fixed point?

Here is what I am trying:

Do a Taylor Series expansion with respect to the fixed point y* and $\rho=\epsilon$, some small value. Then

$\dot{y} = g(y*,\epsilon) + (y-y*)\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \Bigr\rvert_{(y = y*,\rho=\epsilon)} + (\rho-\epsilon)\frac{\partial g}{\partial \rho} \Bigr\rvert_{(y = y*,\rho=\epsilon)} + \frac{1}{2}(y-y*)^{2}\frac{\partial^{2} g}{\partial y^{2}} \Bigr\rvert_{(y = y*,\rho=\epsilon)} $

Then I guess I would set $\dot{y}=0$, recognize the first RHS term is zero. But I'm confused as to how to proceed, and this form doesn't look very helpful.

I'm also wondering if the fixed point solution is unique only if g is continuously differentiable or if there are other conditions I need to consider.

Thank you.

Comment: You know $g(0,0)=0$, so do a Taylor expansion around $y=0,\rho=0$ to get $g(y,\rho)\approx y\cdot\partial g/\partial y+\rho\cdot\partial g/\partial\rho$. Then solve $g(y,\rho)=0$ for $y$ in terms of $\rho$.

Comment: Use also Implicit Function Theorem for $g(y, \rho) = 0$. If $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(0, 0) \neq 0$, then you can write $y$ as a function of $\rho$ in some small neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$, i.e. $y = f(\rho)$ would be an equation of equilibria curve. If $g(y, \rho)$ is sufficiently differentiable function, then you can figure out derivatives of $f(\rho)$ by differentiating $g(f(\rho), \rho) \equiv 0$.